# "Fixing Grub" in single boot installation process

Tags: system-installation, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.02 on my 2011 Macbook Pro following the instructions at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro).

After the installation completed, the impulse to play with my new toy rushed over me and I took a little look around but haven't installed anything or connected to any network. I have rebooted the machine a couple times with no issue.

Now, according the information at the aforementioned page, I need to "fix grub". I only know that grub is a kind of multiboot program. I don't know why I need to fix it. My machine now boots fine. Also, when I follow the instructions to fix grub, I encounter some issues.

During the install, I placed / in the free space in dev/sda. I then made a partition for swap space in dev/sda. I left EFI alone as per the instructions, although I don't know why it was necessary - there are other instructions for the same install that don't say to keep EFI.

Now for the first step in "Fixing Grub", it says to mount the hard drive which Ubuntu was installed on. I think I can skip this since I deleted everything except what was in dev/sda (?).

In step 2 when I enter the command "sudo mount --bind /sys [path] /sys" bash returns "mount: special device sysfs does not exist".

What will installing Grub do for me? And how might one install it in this situation?

Also, why was keeping EFI necessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you reference seems to describe a single-boot (Ubuntu-only, no OS X) installation. If that's what you've done and if your computer boots into the installed Ubuntu, then you're done.

The GRUB "fixing" instructions seem to be geared toward adding the `nomodeset` parameter to the kernel options. This parameter is required on some computers, but not on all of them. In particular, the page was written for a 2013 Mac Pro, but yours is a 2011 model, so they almost certainly differ in important ways, quite possibly including their need for `nomodeset`.

Furthermore, the page describes setting up both rEFInd and GRUB. Either one alone is sufficient. If you see the rEFInd menu when you boot and select an option that boots a Linux kernel (with a name that includes the string `vmlinuz`, as shown when you highlight the option in rEFInd), then you're not even booting via GRUB. If you don't see the rEFInd screen, then chances are you *are* booting via GRUB. You're booting through both of them if you see the rEFInd screen and select an option that boots GRUB (with a name that includes the string `grub`).

Finally, your question refers to "keeping EFI." The [Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) is a type of firmware -- software that's built into a chip on the computer's motherboard. EFI controls the way the computer starts and provides services to help OSes boot. As such, you *must* keep the EFI. (Well, you *could* replace it with Coreboot or something else, but that's a task for uber-geeks. It would also effectively turn your Mac into a non-Mac.) It's not clear to me what you're thinking of when you refer to "keeping EFI," unless perhaps you mean rEFInd. If that's the case, then you need to figure out whether you're booting via rEFInd, GRUB, or both. You could remove one, but there's very little advantage to doing so.